# Number of threads that can run in parallel on a single processor

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Hello I have recently started working with threads in c# and have a question which I was not able to get a clear answer. can multiple threads run in parallel  on a single core processor, Or only one thread can run at a time? I'm running the following program on a single core processor and I see the following output all the time:
Main called
Hello
Main done

which makes me wonder if i ran this on a multi core processor I would probably see the output as:

Main called
Main done
Hello

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Main called");   
    Thread thread = new Thread(SayHello);
    thread.Start();    
    Console.WriteLine("Main done");
    Console.ReadLine();
}

public static void SayHello()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello");
}
```

Comment: This is an awful example of threading. The thread creation takes longer than the actual work the thread does. Overall, with modern C# you shouldn't be ever dealing with threads*. Read Stephen Cleary's blog on "There is no thread".(* unless you are truly CPU bound, which I assure you, you will never be)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A single-core processor can only run one thread at a time, but the operating system uses a mechanism to switch between multiple running threads to give the appearance of concurrency. Although the threads aren't actually running in parallel, you can never know when one thread will stop and the other start.

The many pitfalls of multi-threading are still present, even if you only have one core and one processor.

Like Blindy said, there are various circumstances that can affect which thread runs at which time, but you can't really rely on them.

Answer (score 1):

Depends how you define it, but in your specific case I would argue that yes, they are running in parallel despite being on one processor.

I say that because I/O isn't CPU bound. While your thread sits and waits for the system call to finish, the other threads will run in peace.